# Bootstrap 3: How to get other collapsed navbar links under the screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar with many links/options: 
[image]

When I collapsed it, some options are totally off the screen and I can't click on them:
[image]

In the pic, I can see link 4, but not link 5 and link 6.

Using a dropdown menu will do the same thing.

```css
.navbar {
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
 background-color: #111 !important;
 border-radius: 0px;
}


/* Adjust Toggle button */

.navbar-toggle {
 margin-top: 18px;
}


/* Adjust Navbar Height */

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
 padding-top: 0;
}

.navbar-brand,
.navbar-nav li a {
 color: #FFF !important;
 line-height: 70px;
 height: 70px;
}

.navbar-brand {
 color: #0CF !important;
}

.navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-nav li a:hover {
 background-color: #06C !important;
 color: #0f9 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
 line-height: 40px;
 height: 40px;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-toggle {
 background-color: #222 !important;
}

.navbar div ul li .dropdown-menu {
 background-color: #222;
 border-top: 2px solid #09f;
}

/* Nav Affix */
nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
.affix + .container {
 padding-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="308">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <i class="fa fa-adjust" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     Brand
    </a>
   </div>
   
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
     <li><a href="#">Storyline</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Characters</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <!--li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Misc<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li-->
     <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.
<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>.


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is not enough space for all of them... scroll further? doesn't that work?

Comment: I scroll down to the bottom, there are still some links off the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your javascript probably. I see there is class .affix-top getting added to the  .navbar .navbar-default. Remove that and your nav will scroll properly.

Comment: The javascript files I use are jQuery and Bootstrap js. I use Affix because when I scrolldown, I want the navbar to stay at the top of the screen.

Comment: Well, that is what is preventing you to scroll. Maybe a javascript function where if nav is open to remove that affix class.

Comment: Is it possible to add another scrollbar inside then navbar then?